# Размер таблицы в MySql не уменьшается при очистке значений. Как быть?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица, в которой хранится информация по email рассылке для каждого пользователя (тема письма, текст письма, статус отправки и т.д.). В таблицу добавляется около 30 000 записей в день. Это увеличивает таблицу на 300 Мб в день.

Для того чтобы уменьшить размер таблицы, я очищаю поле "текст письма" для всех записей со статусом "отправлено". Размер в этом случае должен уменьшиться в разы. Но этого не происходит. Размер таблицы остался прежним.

Почему так происходит? Как уменьшить размер таблицы при очистке полей?

Тип таблицы — Innodb.

PS. Просьба не писать сообщения, наподобие "таблицу организовать лучше по другому" и тому подобные сообщения. Вопрос состоит в другом, а именно — как уменьшить размер таблицы, очищая поля записей?

Comment: может вариант удалять эти записи вовсе.

Comment: не вариант, нужно вести статистику

Comment: может это база где-то кеширует данные.

Comment: Читаем [File Space Management](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-file-space.html), особенно абзац, начинающийся со слов "When you delete data from a table ...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла команда `OPTIMIZE TABLE tableName`

Answer (score -2):

- Делаем бакап БД
- удаляем БД
- останавливаем mysql
- в my.cnf удаляем innodb_data_file_path и добавляем параметр innodb_file_per_table
- восстанавливаем БД

После этого каждая таблица БД будет в отдельно файле, а команда optimize table будет уменьшать размер.

Comment: это вы таким способом предлагаете на проде делать ? :)

Comment: Все мы грешны )